# Can not log in my account using google chrome

Tags: support, google-chrome, login

Whenever I am trying to log in my stack exchange account through google chrome, it says the following: 
[image]

The problem was not there few days ago. But I can open my account using Mozilla Firefox. Why is that happening ? How can I fix this problem? Can someone help? I want to use google chrome as it works much faster (in my case).

After Pressing  Ctrl-Shift-J to open the JavaScript console, It shows the following: [image]

UPDATE: I reinstalled google chrome and the problem still remains. Now after Pressing  Ctrl-Shift-J to open the JavaScript console, It shows the following: [image] [image]

Comment: Check your security settings in chrome, and make sure JavaScript isn't blocked for any site.

Comment: Can you be more specific ? I did not change anything in my chrome settings . So, I do not know which one to check.

Comment: Press Ctrl-Shift-J to open the JavaScript console. What messages do you get there?

Comment: @cheapeffectivedietpills I have added the screen shots after pressing Ctrl-Shift-J. I have little knowledge about the problem. Sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you have installed *Website Logon* Chrome extension. As far as I know, it is a legitimate extension, but it appears to either have a temporary malfunction, or to be incompatible with Stack Exchange logging in process. Suggestion: either disable the extension  for this one site (if possible), or remove it altogether.

---

*Update, taken from comments*: So, the problem is that your Chrome is so incredibly old that it can't properly interact with Google's site anymore. The current version of Chrome is 34. It's not surprising that the problem appeared suddenly; Google could have tweaked things on their end without bothering to maintain compatibility with Chrome 16. Solution: either upgrade Chrome or use another browser. Using very old browsers is not a good idea anyway.

Comment: Yes ,you are right. I have removed the extension altogether. But still the problem persists. May be I have to uninstall the google chrome and reinstall it again.

Comment: @learner No harm in trying to reinstall. If the problem remains, look at the JavaScript console again and post an update.

Comment: @learner So, jQuery fails to load for some reason from a Google server. What happens when you click this link: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js  -- do you get `/*! jQuery v1.7.1 jquery.com` or something else?

Comment: I tried to open the link (you gave) from google chrome. But It gives the following notice: Incorrect certificate for host.
The server presented a certificate that doesn't match built-in expectations. These expectations are included for certain, high-security web sites in order to protect you.
Error 150 (net::ERR_SSL_PINNED_KEY_NOT_IN_CERT_CHAIN): The server's certificate appears to be a forgery.

Comment: So, I can not open the link from chrome.

Comment: @learner If you google "Error 150 (net::ERR_SSL_PINNED_KEY_NOT_IN_CERT_CHAIN):", you'll see this is an issue with Chrome, that arises in versions that are either very old and unsupported, or very new and untested. What version of Chrome do you have now? ([related](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/18300))

Comment: I can not exactly say the version of the chrome. I went to the chrome icon at the desktop and then went to the properties. But could not find the version. But whatever version it might be ,it worked well until 2 days ago and that is what puzzled me ..

Comment: @learner If you type `chrome://chrome/` in the address bar, it should show the version.

Comment: I have got its version .It is 16.0.899.0

Comment: I typed chrome://chrome/ in the address bar of the chrome but it says : This webpage is not available
The webpage at chrome://chrome/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
Error 300 (net::ERR_INVALID_URL): Unknown error.

Comment: I got the version from the software that was present in my computer.

Comment: @learner So, the problem is that your Chrome is so incredibly old that it can't properly interact with Google's site anymore. The current version of Chrome is 34. It's not surprising that the problem appeared suddenly; Google could have tweaked things on their end without bothering to maintain compatibility with Chrome 16. Solution: either upgrade Chrome or use another browser. Using very old browsers is not a good idea anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much for your good advice and time. I must follow your advice by upgrading my chrome.